# JQGrid maintain data on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqgrid which is declared in  user control and referred in web page. Data is loaded on button click event using ajax call. Everything works fine except when  a post-back is triggered on page to do some server processing data vanishes on grid. User as to search again by clicking button to get results back. Is there a way to retain data on a jqgrid when post-back is done.

Answer (score 0):

It would be way to expensive to try and retain the grid data during a postback.  You shouldn't even try to do that.

Your best option is to use ajax for whatever is initiating the full page postback.